# How to make a constructor of a generic type

Tags: java, android, class, generics, constructor

given the the below code,how can i make the constructor of a generic type so that it can accept any class passed to it

**code**:

```
ServiceCtrl(Context ctx, Class<SPPService> sppServiceClass) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
    this.mClass = sppServiceClass;
}

public boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.mCtx.getSystemService(this.mCtx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (this.mClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What about `Class<?>`?

Comment: @Flown would u please provide an example because when i used ? android studion underscores the 2nd line in the constructor with red

Comment: @user2121 : did you change the declaration of `mClass` member  as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ServiceCtrl<E extends Object> {
    private Class<E> mClass;

    ServiceCtrl(Context ctx, Class<E> sppServiceClass) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
        this.mClass = sppServiceClass;
    }

    public boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.mCtx.getSystemService(this.mCtx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (this.mClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2121 add `<E extends Object>` to your class definition, as I edited

Comment: would u please tell me the difference between E and "?" ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, make `sppServiceClass` generic in the constructor ?

If so, you're looking for this :

```
ServiceCtrl(Context ctx, Class<?> clazz) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT : you need to change the declaration of `mClass` as well to `Class<?>`.